# OpenSSH 'Server refused our key' and 'Access denied'

Tags: windows-10, ssh, cygwin, putty, openssh

All configuration seems fine but OpenSSH replies with errors:
2048 bit keys was generated, public one put into `C:\cygwin64\home\user\.ssh\authorized_keys`. When trying to connect using PuTTY to localhost it wont let in.

> Server refused our key

Moreover when using 100% valid credentials for user - OpenSSH won't let in either.

> Access denied

OpenSSH was set up according to [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/).

Log at `C:\cygwin64\var\log\sshd.log` is empty.  How to make it work?

PS. When trying to log in from Cygwin terminal it says:

> Permission denied, please try again.

**UPDATE 2**

When installed bitvise SSH Server. Same story. `Logon to Windows account failed` Such a strange behavior.

**UPDATE 3**

When trying in cmd `runas`:

```
Attempting to start explorer.exe as user "PC\user2" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - explorer.exe
1385: Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.
```

Comment: Are you using the same user in both computers? Without other options, Windows username must be remote ssh key username (user@remotehost).

Comment: I am running it all inside one VM while logged in as a different user.

Answer (score 0):

We could use process monitor and filter the "Access denied" error to have a troubleshoot.

Here is a link for reference:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2013/05/03/using-process-monitor-to-solve-any-problem-including-debugdiag/

Here is the download link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx